# getCurrentFocus() returns null after update android targetSdk from 26 to 33

Tags: android, view

I'm a developer, but I don't often work with Android, and I have an application that switches to overlay mode.

I use **getCurrentFocus()** to remove the old view and add a new view to switch to overlay mode.

In **Android 8** method **MainActivity.getCurrentFocus()** works fine.

However, when updating to **Android 13**, View **MainActivity. getCurrentFocus() returns null**.

I tested on device **Android 10** so i dont think this is device issue.

I searched the log change about **getCurrentFocus()** but didn't see any change.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Below is the pseudo code:

```
MainActivity:
        ServiceConnection serviceConnection = null;
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            ...
            serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection(this);
            ...
        }
    
ServiceConnection : Android.Content.IServiceConnection
    
        MainActivity mainActivity;
        
        public IServiceConnection(MainActivity activity)
        {
            ...
            mainActivity = activity;
            ...
        }
        
        public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            ...
            binder.GetService().UpdateRootView(mainActivity.getCurrentFocus());//getCurrentFocus return is NULL on Android 13
            ...
        }
```

Comment: I had resolved this issue by adding Window.DecorView.RequestFocus() into onResume() method of MainActivity class.
I hope it will usefull for some one facing similar issue.